# Django static files can't be loaded on the google compute engine

Tags: python, django, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, django-staticfiles

I have run the python manage.py runserver command on my computer(windows 10) and it work but when I put all of codes on the google cloud platform compute engine(Ubuntu 16) and run the same command it shows all of the static files are not found. Do anyone knows how to fix it?

settings.py (ignore some irrelative parts)

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: 
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = 
os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework_swagger',

    'restaurants',  # 餐廳APP
    'webpack_loader',  # 整合vue和django套件
    'corsheaders'  # 處理跨域請求套件

    # 'gunicorn',  # 部署用
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
   'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]


ROOT_URLCONF = 'foodies.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 
    'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
     'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../static')],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',

 'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
         ],
     },
 },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'foodies.wsgi.application'

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

 STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../frontend/dist'),
)

WEBPACK_LOADER = {
    'DEFAULT': {
    'BUNDLE_DIR_NAME': '',
    'STATS_FILE': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../webpack- 
   stats.json'),
    }
}


CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
# 允許所有header請求
CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = ('*')
```

static files path
[image]

index.html
[image]

url.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework_swagger.views import get_swagger_view
from django.views.generic import TemplateView


schema_view = get_swagger_view(title='Pastebin API')

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include('restaurants.urls')),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
    path('api-view/', schema_view),
    path('', TemplateView.as_view(
        template_name="index.html"), name='index')
]
```

chrome error messages
[image]

compute engine status
[image]

Comment: Did you run `collectstatic`?

Comment: I did but still not working.

Comment: In development mode (`DEBUG=True`) Django automatically serves static files using `runserver`. In production, you'll need to configure a web server (e.g. nginx) to serve the static files for you.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest reading this:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/deployment/

It has specific and exact instructions on the expected deployment of static files.

Comment: I have run python mange.py collectstatic but it still not working. I will try to set nginx to serve satic files.

Comment: But It's still confused that it could run in local instead of on the cloud.

Comment: If you're into reading the Django code base, it might help you understand.  https://github.com/django/django  Either way, a deployed project can run as it did when you were doing local development if you want, but its not recommended.

Comment: here s a great write up in the medium. https://codeburst.io/beginners-guide-to-deploying-a-django-postgresql-project-on-google-cloud-s-flexible-app-engine-e3357b601b91#4355